# # google classroom API

Tags: google-classroom

I am new to google classroom API, I want to know whether API has one capability which full fill our requirement.

Requirement:

Assume that I have one button called courses on our own web application, when I click on the button it shows list of courses that I have, so now what I want know is can I put a button beside it so that when I click the button it should create google courses programatically with respective names.

Does google classroom API has that capability?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, the [Classroom Share button](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth#androidIdTokens) may be a simple solution. Otherwise you can call [courses.list()](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) with the `studentId` or `teacherId` parameter in order to get a list of courses for your account.

Comment: I think the question was about creating courses, not listing.  Listing is something prapoorn already had working.

Answer (score 1):

The API contains a [`courses.create`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/create) method which can be used to create courses.